# Decide how many documents to pull from Database for memory utilization

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, memory-management, mongoengine

Im using python 2.7 with mongodb as my database. (actually it dosen't matter which database i use)

In my database i have millions of documents, from time to time i need to iterate over all of them.

It's not realistic to pull all the documents in one query because that will kill the memory, instead i pull each iteration 1000 documents and iterate them, when i finish i'm pulling another 1000 and so on.

I was wondering if there is any formula to calculate the best number of pulling each iteration from the database.

I couldn't find over the internet something that answer my issue.

Basically my question is what is the best way of finding the best number to pull from the database in each iteration.

Comment: Find out the size of document and amount of memory you can allocate for records (or you are okay to allocate). Then (Amount of memory you can allocate/ Amount of memory for one document) is no.of documents you can iterate in one iteration. That should be your best number of records to pull. Try with multiple combination and check performance also. No. giving best system/operation performance and taking permissible memory is best for you.

Comment: I think its not a realy good idea to reach close to memory limit. You are reading 1000 records in one query which shuld be efficient as it will require less memory and network transfer time.

Answer (score 0):

The only chance you have is to take some sample documents to calculate their average size. The more difficult part is to know what the available memory is, keeping in mind that there are other processes that consume ram in parallel!

So even when you take this road, you need to keep an amount of ram free. I doubt that the effort is worth it.